# AVR32 UC3A0 how to utilize USART interrupt example and receive string then do something

Tags: c, string, interrupt, avr, uart

I am having some trouble, and I cannot tell if it's my understanding of the Atmel syntax, the Atmel Studio 6.0 or, the program itself.
I cannot seem to get the interrupt handler to receive a simple string then do something.  I have success with just implimenting a single character turning an LED when USART receives one character it turns the LED on, then if it receives a different character it turns the LED off.  By the way I have a design board that the program is having some trouble getting to the receive sub routine because the send code within the main is so large, so it was suggested to me to utilize interrupts to fix this. 
By the way, I am trialing this program on an EVK1100 AVR32 board MCU:AT32UC3A0512-U, not sure if any of you have played with these before, but they're pretty great. Not sure I like Atmel syntax though.
Anyway, you can see I'm doing nothing in the main at the moment until I get the receive portion working.

I'm fairly new to interrupts in the Atmel world.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I made just a few modifications to the built in ASF USART interrup "INTC" project example.

Thanks,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <avr32/io.h>
#include "compiler.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "print_funcs.h"
#include "intc.h"
#if defined (__GNUC__)
#  if   defined (__AVR32_AP7000__)
#    include "pm_at32ap7000.h"
#  else
#    include "power_clocks_lib.h"
#  endif
#elif defined (__ICCAVR32__) || defined (__AAVR32__)
#  if  defined (__AT32AP7000__)
#    include "pm_at32ap7000.h"
#  else
#    include "power_clocks_lib.h"
#  endif
#endif
#include "gpio.h"
#include "usart.h"
//#include "conf_example.h"    
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz

#if BOARD == EVK1100
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART1)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_CLOCK_MASK      AVR32_USART1_CLK_PBA
#  define EXAMPLE_PDCA_CLOCK_HSB        AVR32_PDCA_CLK_HSB
#  define EXAMPLE_PDCA_CLOCK_PB         AVR32_PDCA_CLK_PBA
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART1_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#endif
    /**
     * \brief The USART interrupt handler.
     *
     * \note The `__attribute__((__interrupt__))' (under GNU GCC for AVR32) and
     *       `__interrupt' (under IAR Embedded Workbench for Atmel AVR32) C function
 *       attributes are used to manage the `rete' instruction.
 */
#if defined (__GNUC__)
__attribute__((__interrupt__))
#elif defined(__ICCAVR32__)
__interrupt
#endif

static void usart_int_handler(void)
{   
    static char Cmnd[30];
    int index = 0;
    int c;

    usart_read_char(EXAMPLE_USART, &c);
    Cmnd[index++] = c;

if (c = '\r')
{
    Cmnd[index] = '\0';
    usart_write_line(EXAMPLE_USART, Cmnd);
}

}   


/**
 * \brief The main function.
 *
 * It sets up the USART module on EXAMPLE_USART. The terminal settings are 57600
 * 8N1.
 * Then it sets up the interrupt handler and waits for a USART interrupt to
 * trigger.
 */
int main(void)
{
    static const gpio_map_t USART_GPIO_MAP =
    {
        {EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN, EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION},
        {EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN, EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION}
    };

    // USART options.
    static const usart_options_t USART_OPTIONS =
    {
        .baudrate     = 57600,
        .charlength   = 8,
        .paritytype   = USART_NO_PARITY,
        .stopbits     = USART_1_STOPBIT,
        .channelmode  = USART_NORMAL_CHMODE
    };

#if BOARD == EVK1100 || BOARD == EVK1101 || BOARD == UC3C_EK \
    || BOARD == EVK1104 || BOARD == EVK1105 || BOARD == STK600_RCUC3L0 \
    || BOARD == STK600_RCUC3D
    /*
     * Configure Osc0 in crystal mode (i.e. use of an external crystal
     * source, with frequency FOSC0) with an appropriate startup time then
     * switch the main clock source to Osc0.
     */
    pcl_switch_to_osc(PCL_OSC0, FOSC0, OSC0_STARTUP);

#elif BOARD == STK1000
    pm_reset();
#elif BOARD == UC3L_EK
    /*
     * Note: on the AT32UC3L-EK board, there is no crystal/external clock
     * connected to the OSC0 pinout XIN0/XOUT0. We shall then program the
     * DFLL and switch the main clock source to the DFLL.
     */
    pcl_configure_clocks(&pcl_dfll_freq_param);
    /*
     * Note: since it is dynamically computing the appropriate field values
     * of the configuration registers from the parameters structure, this
     * function is not optimal in terms of code size. For a code size
     * optimal solution, it is better to create a new function from
     * pcl_configure_clocks_dfll0() and modify it to use preprocessor
     * computation from pre-defined target frequencies.
     */
#end if

    // Assign GPIO to USART.
    gpio_enable_module(USART_GPIO_MAP,
        sizeof(USART_GPIO_MAP) / sizeof(USART_GPIO_MAP[0]));

    // Initialize USART in RS232 mode.
    usart_init_rs232(EXAMPLE_USART, &USART_OPTIONS,
        EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ);
    print(EXAMPLE_USART, ".: Using interrupts with the USART :.\r\n\r\n");

    // Disable all interrupts.
    Disable_global_interrupt();

    // Initialize interrupt vectors.
    INTC_init_interrupts();

    /*
     * Register the USART interrupt handler to the interrupt controller.
     * usart_int_handler is the interrupt handler to register.
     * EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ is the IRQ of the interrupt handler to register.
     * AVR32_INTC_INT0 is the interrupt priority level to assign to the
     * group of this IRQ.
     */
    INTC_register_interrupt(&usart_int_handler, EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ, AVR32_INTC_INT0);

    // Enable USART Rx interrupt.
    EXAMPLE_USART->ier = AVR32_USART_IER_RXRDY_MASK;
    print(EXAMPLE_USART, "Type a character to use the interrupt handler."
        "\r\nIt will show up on your screen.\r\n\r\n");

    // Enable all interrupts.
    Enable_global_interrupt();

    /**
     * We have nothing left to do in the main, so we may switch to a device
     * sleep mode: we just need to be sure that the USART module will be
     * still be active in the chosen sleep mode. The sleep mode to use is
     * the FROZEN sleep mode: in this mode the PB clocks are still active
     * (so the USART module which is on the Peripheral Bus will still be
     * active while the CPU and HSB will be stopped).
     * --
     * Modules communicating with external circuits should normally be
     * disabled before entering a sleep mode that will stop the module
     * operation: this is not the case for the FROZEN sleep mode.
     * --
     * When the USART interrupt occurs, this will wake the CPU up which will
     * then execute the interrupt handler code then come back to the
     * while(1) loop below to execute the sleep instruction again.
     */

    while(1)
    {
        /*
         * If there is a chance that any PB write operations are
         * incomplete, the CPU should perform a read operation from any
         * register on the PB bus before executing the sleep
         * instruction.
         */
        AVR32_INTC.ipr[0];  // Dummy read


        /*
         * When the device wakes up due to an interrupt, once the
         * interrupt has been serviced, go back into FROZEN sleep mode.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: It is been years I did something like this but I do not see you clearing any interrupt flags in your ISR. Also you should check the source of interrupt (if it is TX or RX) so you do not hang the ISR waiting if buffer full/empty.

Comment: @emacs drives me nuts Kindly read the tag description before starting an edit spree. The avr tag says "AVR refers to two families of either 8- or 32-bit RISC microcontrollers". If you think that the tag isn't to be used like that any longer, the solution isn't to apply some private secret meaning to the tag "this is only 8 bitters", but to raise the matter to SO meta and then change the tag wiki to disambiguate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your interrupt handlers short. Interrupt handlers or ISRs are executed usually with interrupts disabled. Their goal is to get in, do something, and get out quickly. If you have other interrupts running (like a real-time clock for example), they are blocked out while you're in the ISR and that can cause problems such as lost interrupts.

The best thing to do here would be to declare the input buffer as a global static. Also define a `static uchar_t have_line` or similar, and in the ISR, save each character until either the buffer is full (an important check!), or you receive a CR (\r). Also check for newline (\n). Save a zero to null-terminate the buffer, and then set `have_line = 1`.

In your main loop, wait for `have_line` to be non-zero, and then process what's in the input buffer. Finally, set have_line back to zero.

That way, your ISR is brief and fairly robust.

In your sample code, does the function `usart_write_line` require interrupts to be enabled?

Oops!  Sorry, I just noticed that your index isn't a static variable. That means it'll be initialized to zero each time the routine is called. Add a static declarator in front of *int index* and that should sort it out.

Comment: Yes I believe it does require interrupts to be enabled.  And they are.